# Break out of innermost loop in nested while loops in perl: Label not found

Tags: perl

I have a problem with breaking out of the innermost enclosing loop in doubly nested `while` loops.
Consider:

```
use v5.14;

my $i=0;
while ($i<=1) {
    my $j=0;
    do {
        last if $j==2;
        say $j++;
    } while ($j<4);
    $i++;
}
```

The output is here:

```
0
1
```

whereas the expected output should be:

```
0
1
0
1
```

Adding a label to the innermost enclosing loop:

```
my $i=0;
while ($i<=1) {
    my $j=0;
    LINE: do {
        last LINE if $j==2;
        say $j++;
    } while ($j<4);
    $i++;
}
```

gives error:

```
Label not found for "last LINE" at ./p.pl line 9.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `last` inside `do{}` block, but you can

```
my $i=0;
while ($i<=1) {
    my $j=0;
    LINE: { 
      do {
        last LINE if $j==2;
        say $j++;
      } while ($j<4); 
    }
    $i++;
}
```

or

```
my $i=0;
OUTER: while ($i<=1) {
    my $j=0;
    LINE: do {
        next OUTER if $j==2;
        say $j++;
    } while ($j<4);
}
continue {
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Re "You can't use last inside do{} block", Sure you can. It just doesn't cause it to loop since `do BLOCK` isn't a loop. But `while` is. Why didn't you explain why `last` can't make the `while` exit?

Answer (score 8):

You can only use `last`, `next` and `redo` in loops that use a `BLOCK`.

- `while (EXPR) BLOCK`
- `until (EXPR) BLOCK`
- `for (LIST) BLOCK`
- `for (EXPR; EXPR; EXPR) BLOCK`
- `BLOCK`

You can't use them on loops created by statement modifiers<sup>[1]</sup>.

- `EXPR while EXPR;`
- `EXPR until EXPR;`

`do BLOCK while EXPR;` is just a case of `EXPR while EXPR;`. The loop doesn't have a `BLOCK` for `last` to work on. It's merely a `while` statement modifier that's modifying `do` function<sup>[2]</sup>. The `do` function being modified has a `BLOCK`, but `do` is not a loop.

---

You could add a loop to `last` out of, such as a bare loop (`BLOCK`) that's normally executed only once.

```
my $i=0;
while ($i<=1) {
    LOOP: {
        my $j=0;
        do {
            last if $j==2;
            say $j++;
        } while ($j<4);
    }
    ++$i;
}
```

But if we could make sure `++$i` always got executed, we could just `next` the outer loop.

```
my $i=0;
while ($i<=1) {
    my $j=0;
    do {
        next if $j==2;
        say $j++;
    } while ($j<4);
} continue {
    ++$i;
}
```

The above simplifies to

```
for (my $i=0; $i<=1; ++$i) {
    my $j=0;
    do {
        next if $j==2;
        say $j++;
    } while ($j<4);
}
```

which simplifies to

```
for my $i (0..1) {
    my $j=0;
    do {
        next if $j==2;
        say $j++;
    } while ($j<4);
}
```

Of course, that assumes we need to preserve the `do while`. If not, we can just write

```
for my $i (0..1) {
    for my $j (0..3) {
        last if $j==2;
        say $j;
    }
}
```

---

1. Or so I thought. Turns out it works for `for`!!!!

   ```
   >perl -we"print($_), (($_ == 5) && last) for 1..10; print(qq{\ndone\n});"
   12345
   done
   ```
2. Well, not quite "merely". It's special-cased to be bottom-tested instead of top-tested.

Comment: +1 : `"It's special-cased to be bottom-tested instead of top-tested."` I've always known that, yet never paused to realize that it is the exception to the rule. Perl is truly a bottomless ocean.

Comment: @Miller, WTF? Why does it work for `for`? sigh. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As [`perldoc do`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html) and everyone has already stated:

> - `do BLOCK`
>
>   Not really a function. Returns the value of the last command in the sequence of commands indicated by BLOCK. When modified by the [`while`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/while.html) or [`until`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/until.html) loop modifier, executes the BLOCK once before testing the loop condition. (On other statements the loop modifiers test the conditional first.)
>
>   do BLOCK does *not* count as a loop, so the loop control statements [`next`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/next.html), [`last`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/last.html), or [`redo`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/redo.html) cannot be used to leave or restart the block. See [`perlsyn`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html) for alternative strategies.

The deeper tribal knowledge with regard to this is that you should reserve these statement modifiers for single line or at most two line statements.

If you want a multiline block to be a loop, the coder should be able to observe that from the very first line.  Therefore, instead of ever using a statement modifier with a `do BLOCK`, setup an infinite loop and create your test to break out of it at the end:

```
while (1) {
    ...

    last if EXPR;
}
```

This would change your somewhat contrived example to the following:

```
use v5.14;

my $i = 0;
while ($i <= 1) {
    my $j = 0;
    while (1) {
        last if $j == 2;
        say $j++;
        last if $j >= 4;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really must:

```
my $i=0;
while ($i++<=1) {
    my $j=0;
    LINE: {
      do {
        last LINE if $j==2;
        say $j++;
      } while ($j<4);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As noted by others, you can't use `last` with [`do`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html):

> do BLOCK does not count as a loop, so the loop control statements next, last, or redo cannot be used to leave or restart the block.

Another solution is to use another `while` loop:

```
my $i = 0;
while ($i <= 1) {
    my $j = 0;
    while($j < 4) {
        last if $j == 2;
        say $j++;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

or, with `for` loops:

```
for my $i (0 .. 1) {
    for my $j (0 .. 3) {
        last if $j == 2;
        say $j;
    }
}
```

Comment: Re "do BLOCK does not count as a loop", but `while` does, and `while` is present here. Incomplete answer.